# How to best query if an expression contains Symbol/variable

Tags: pattern-matching, variable

Say I have this expression, among many:

```
lhospital[-((ao^3 (r2 r3 rb rc + 
r1 (r4 ra rc + r3 rb rc + 
r3 ra (rb + rc))) rgsink vref + (r1 + r2) (r3 + 
r4) (ra rc rgsink + rb rc rgsink + ra rb (rc + rgsink)) vth + 
ao (r2 (r4 ra rb rgsink vref + r3 rb rc rgsink vth + 
r3 ra (rb rc vth + rc rgsink vth + 
rb rgsink (vref + vth))) + 
r1 (2 r3 rb rc rgsink vth + r4 rb rc rgsink vth + 
r4 ra (rb rc vth + rc rgsink vth + 
rb rgsink (vref + vth)) + 
r3 ra (2 rb rc vth + 2 rc rgsink vth + 
rb rgsink (vref + 2 vth)))) + 
ao^2 (r2 (r3 rb rc + r4 (ra + rb) rc + 
r3 ra (rb + rc)) rgsink vref + 
r1 (r4 (rb rc + ra (rb + rc)) rgsink vref + 
r3 (ra rc rgsink (vref + vth) + rb rc rgsink (vref + vth) +
ra rb (rc vth + 
rgsink (2 vref + vth))))))/(r2 r4 (-((-1 + 
ao^2) ra rc rgsink) - (-1 + ao^2) rb rc rgsink + 
ra rb (rc + rgsink - ao rgsink)) + 
r2 r3 ((1 + ao - ao^2) ra rc rgsink - (-1 + ao) (1 + 
ao)^2 rb rc rgsink + (1 + ao) ra rb (rc + rgsink - 
ao rgsink)) + (1 + 
ao) r1 r3 ((1 + ao - ao^2) ra rc rgsink + (1 + ao - 
ao^2) rb rc rgsink + (1 + ao) ra rb (rc + rgsink - 
ao rgsink)) + 
r1 r4 ((1 + ao - ao^2) rb rc rgsink + (1 + 
ao) ra (-((-1 + ao^2) rc rgsink) + 
rb (rc + rgsink - ao rgsink))))), ao]
```

I want the whole proof to be as automated as possible. As in, I don't want to dice-up & copy-paste anything, so to make sure I've inserted a blunders in the math. If there's a step,  it's gotta be in code.

How do I filter these expressions to find out if `ao` is in the expression as it is, so to know if I need to apply certain functions? I've been tempted to ToString everything run StringMatchQ, but that can't be right. Any better way for scanning variable names?

Comment: **How do I filter these expressions to find out if ao is in the expression as it is** may be try the command [FreeQ](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FreeQ.html) ?

Comment: To get positions: `Position[expr, ao]` where `expr` is the expression in the OP.

Comment: Got it. Thanks to both.